# Does Windows 10 Home includes hyper-v?

Tags: windows, hyper-v

I will upgrade my windows 8.1 Basic to 10. 
Does windows 10 Home support hyper-v?
If it is not, there is other way to run hyper-v on my device beside upgrading to Pro?

Comment: Sorry, I thought there was as MS provides a link to download Hyper-V for Windows 10.  After I actually tried to download it, though, I found it to be nothing more than a .docx talking about using the product.  Hah.

Answer (score 7):

No, hyper-v is only included in Pro. You can use VmWare or Virtualbox instead. Also, 8.1 non-Pro, turns into 10 Home, not Basic.