# I don't find Hyper-v in "add/remove windows features

Tags: hyper-v

I want to run the virtual machine from Windows phone using visual studio 
But I can't founded it in Windows features 
I upgraded to Windows 10 but the problem was not resolved

[image]

Comment: You have either `Windows 10 Professional` or `Windows 10 Enterprise` installed?  You also have no other virtualization software installed?

Comment: Windows 10 famille unilingue and I have no virtualisation software installed

Comment: `Windows 10 Home Single Language` does not contain this feature which is the feature you have.  Upgrade to `Windows 10 Professional` if you want Hyper-V

Answer (score 1):

Hyper-V is a feature of Windows 10 Pro and Enterprise (64-bit), and therefore is not available in the Home/base version of Windows 10, or in *any* 32-bit edition.

Related SU question: [Does Windows 10 Home includes hyper-v?](https://superuser.com/questions/948086/does-windows-10-home-includes-hyper-v)

Perhaps also chek out this [Windows 10 edition feature comparison chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions#Comparison_chart), or [this one from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/WindowsForBusiness/Compare).